# Recent Research Topics in Macroeconomics (Hopefully Growth Theory)

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, economic-growth, applied-econometrics, solow

Im in my last year as undergraduate and i have the opportunity to make a tesis, i have strong foundations in econometrics and macroeconomics but I don't know what the latest research on macroeconomics is, im really interested in growth theory. If you guys can give me tips on the best economists in growth theory, articles to read, new models, new points of view, etc, I would appreciate it very much.
Also, if you can recommend books on advanced macroeconomics, that would be great, the last two I read were Advanced Macroeconomics by David Romer and Dynamic Macroeconomics by George Alogoskoufis.

Comment: it is not really that recent, but the 2009 textbook "Introduction to Modern Economic Growth" by Acemoglu should help you to go deeper into the topic beyond the texts you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I bought it about a week ago. Do you know a book like this but more recent?

Comment: Sadly, I don't.